# Why oh my zsh require manually click Q after some AWS cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Before I install oh my zsh, I just run some command, terminal has records

```sh
aws sts get-caller-identity


{
    "UserId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Account": "12345678",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/yang.fei"
}
```

But when I install oh my zsh, need manually click Q to exit

```sh
aws sts get-caller-identity

# it will open a new
{
    "UserId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Account": "12345678",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/yang.fei"
}
(END)

# after I click Q, there is no record is terminal history
aws sts get-caller-identity --output json 
aws sts get-caller-identity --output json
```

Comment: because of V2. If you do not specify otherwise, the pager AWS CLI version 2 uses by default is less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the cli pager, see [the dos](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html):

- open the `~/.aws/config` file
- add `cli_pager=` the `[default]` section

Comment: Thank you very much.    

The following example sets the default to disable the use of a pager.   
```bash
[default]
cli_pager=

```

Comment: that unfortunately didn't work for me.. I still need to press `q` every time :/